# Convert the following equation to a first-order vector differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

How can I write the following equation as a first-order vector differential equation?

\begin{align} m \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}^2 t}  + 2 \gamma m
 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} + kx = 0 . \end{align}

This is a question originally from Kurt Jacobs, question 3 in chapter 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new variable $y(t) = \dot x(t)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}\dot x(t) &= \hspace{4.8em} y(t) \\ \dot y(t) &= -\frac k m x(t)  -2\gamma y(t) \end{align*}$$

Then if we take $v=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\frac k m & -2\gamma\end{bmatrix}$, we have the following vector differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} v(t) = A v(t).$$

Comment: Thank you @'Trevor Norton'